# Is there any Autocomplete library for city country list other than 'google places autocomplete' in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want library which has Autocomplete feature for City. When city is inputted, it will show its relevant country and when selected will display. Similar to 'Google Autocomplete Places' (GAP).In short any alternative to GAP in Reactjs.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the Autocomplete component and the list of available cities are two different pieces to the puzzle. Sure there are packages out there that combine the two, but you should be able to use any React Autocomplete component, like https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized-select/ for example (not actively maintained), and then use whatever list of cities from wherever.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for something like this :-

[`CodePen`](https://codepen.io/LucaColonnello/pen/waYppV)

Even the React autocomplete is very good npm package for autocompletion
Here is the Link :-

[React Autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-places-autocomplete)

Comment: But it uses google api.Since, it enforces to make it billing and thus obstructs to use api. Any other alternative

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a solid library: [React Places Autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-places-autocomplete)